# Timed Mule Web Service Client Flow

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I've searched the forums for an answer to this. I found one almost identical question, though the answer left me still wondering.

An almost identical post was found here:

[Mule - Schedule a flow to consume a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12029203/mule-schedule-a-flow-to-consume-a-web-service/15005665#15005665)

This poster stated the problem I am having very well.

I am also new to Mule and am trying to do the very same thing. I didnt realize I needed a payload since I thought the operation specification was essentially the payload.

Notice that I have a flow that includes cxf:jaxws-client and that client specifies a URL for the service and an operation "listTest".

What other payload do i need to specify in order to actually execute the service request?

I tried to add a dummy payload to the event generator (as suggested in referenced post), and that doesnt make a difference.

When I execute the mule application, and monitor the "test auditor web service" (using wireshark) i see four requests go out for the wsdl, and i see that wsdl returned, but i dont actually see the listTest operation getting invoked.

My flow is:

```
   <http:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape"
    validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0"
    receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000"
    socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP\HTTPS" />
    <flow name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1" doc:name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1">
    <quartz:outbound-endpoint jobName="GetTestList"
        repeatInterval="10000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job jobGroupName="GetTestList" />
    </quartz:outbound-endpoint>
    <cxf:jaxws-client operation="listTest"
        clientClass="server.TestService_Service" port="TestServicePort"
        wsdlLocation="http://192.168.66.7:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService?wsdl"
        doc:name="SOAPY" />
    <outbound-endpoint
        address="http://192.168.66.7:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService"
        doc:name="HTTP" />
    <logger message="Received HTTP Response #[payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <!-- <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://192.168.66.17:8080/TestAuditorWebApp/TestService" 
        doc:name="HTTP"/> -->
    <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\tmp"
        outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime].txt"
        responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Output File" />
</flow>
```

I am not only new to mule, but as well to stack overflow. So if there was a better way for me to ask a related question, please advise and excuse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What object parameter(s) does the `listTest` method on `server.TestService_Service` take?

Comment: public class TestService_Service extends Service

Comment: @WebResult(name = "listTestResponse", targetNamespace = "http://server/", partName = "parameters")
    @Action(input = "http://server/TestService/listTestRequest", output = "http://server/TestService/listTestResponse")
    @WebMethod
    public ListTestResponse listTest(
        @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "listTest", targetNamespace = "http://server/")
        ListTest parameters
    );

Comment: <message name="listTest">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:listTest"/>
  </message>
    <operation name="listTest">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>

Comment: Still learning to use this comment feature:

listTest shouldnt take any arguments. The web service has a no-argument listTest signature

When I replace the quartz timer, and cxf component with a file input endpoint containing the following data things work just fine:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:listTest xmlns:ns2="http://server/"/>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

I feel like i'm very close with the soap/cxf component. Something simple is escaping me.

Comment: Never put code/XML in comment. Edit your original question with "Edit 1" " Edit 2"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Quartz, you can use a `poll` message processor to generate the instances of `ListTest` you need.

Assuming this class FQDN is `server.TestService.ListTest` (you didn't tell), the following should work:

```
<flow name="TestAuditorClient_CheckerFlow1">
  <poll frequency="10000">
    <set-payload value="#[lt=new server.TestService.ListTest(); lt.aField='aValue'; lt]" />
  </poll>
...
```

Notice how you can set values on the POJO directly from the expression that creates it.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying your suggestion:
 Execution of the expression "lt=new server.TestService.ListTest(); lt.aField='aValue'; lt" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload is of type: String

Comment: Well, this is an *example*. You didn't specify the fields `ListTest` supports. You didn't specify its FQDN. Thus you have to adapt the expression to make it work with your actual code.

Comment: Yay. This worked:

  <poll frequency="10000">
   <set-payload
    value="#[lt=new server.ListTest(); lt]" />
  </poll>

Comment: Now that you've helped me to get past this. It does strike me that setting payload in this fashion is a bit odd. What is the alternative way to modify the flow (for example with a java component) that would allow me to pass new server.ListTest() into the cxf component? 

Oddly none of the cxf web service client samples that i've seen on the mule website talk to this fairly critical element of the payload definition.

Comment: If you set no field on the POJO, you can simply go with `<set-payload value="#[new server.ListTest()]" />`. You could use a custom component or message processor to do this, instead of using a MEL expression, but I don't see why you find it odd to use MEL in a place it's perfectly fitted for the job.

Comment: This worked for me, and is even cleaner:

        <component class="wsdl.Payload" doc:name="Java"/>


Tyvm for all your help.

Comment: What does `wsdl.Payload` do? Create instances of `server.ListTest`? In `OnCall()`? I fail to see how this is better than using MEL, unit testing maybe?

Comment: My response to "MEL" is really one of unfamiliarity more than anything. I agree it does seem suited for the job. I guess it will take a bit of getting used to for me.